# nltk language model TypeError:ngarms() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pad_symbol'

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram, language-model

I'm executing the following code:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.model import Ngram
lm = NgramModel(2, brown.words(categories='news'), estimator=None)
```

But I got an error:

[image]

I really don't know why I do have this problem; is it a bug from nltk code? Has anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try updating the nltk version?

Comment: Ah the infamous `NgramModel` in `NLTK`! What's the output of `python -c "import nltk;print nltk.__version__"`? The latest version of NLTK should have deprecated the module until further notice.

Answer (score 1):

Since this answer hasn't been updated in 3+ years, here is an example of the ngram model code in NLTK v3.5

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.lm import KneserNeyInterpolated
from nltk.lm.preprocessing import padded_everygram_pipeline

# create a bigram model using Kneser-Ney smoothing
lm = KneserNeyInterpolated(2) # could also be MLE(2)
# use the Brown Corpus to train the language model
# padding adds <s> tags before a sentence, and </s> tags after a sentence
train, vocab = padded_everygram_pipeline(order=2, text=brown.sents())
# optionally, choose a category of the Brown Corpus to train a language model
# train, vocab = padded_everygram_pipeline(order=2, text=brown.sents(categories='news'))
lm.fit(train, vocab) # fit the trained model
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, nltk.model still has some bugs in it, and it is not in nltk-master for that reason [NgramModel bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443084/is-there-an-alternate-for-the-now-removed-module-nltk-model-ngrammodel). Since the model branch is still under development, I downloaded the most recent version and still got the same error as in your post.

If you need this module and are comfortable downgrading versions, then I found a release that has a working verison. [NLTK 2.0.4](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/releases/tag/2.0.4)

Comment: It runs but it's not working *correctly*, use with caution =)